# Delete from session at specific Index Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a form which adds bill details, like in the screenshot:

[image]

In this form person first add the entries that are stored in the session through this code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(string nameValueInsert, string nameValueSubmit, CreateBillViewModel model, int? Patient_id)
{
    int count = 0;
    var button = nameValueInsert ?? nameValueSubmit;

    if (button == "Insert")
    {
        if (Session["templist"] == null)
        {
            List<PatientViewModel> lst = new List<PatientViewModel>();

            lst.Add(new PatientViewModel()
                    {   Count = count,
                        PatientAppointmentID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["PatientAppointmentID"]),
                        // BillNo = Request.Form["BillNo"],
                        Amount = double.Parse(Request.Form["Amount"]),
                        Description = Request.Form["Description"]
                    });
            Session["templist"] = lst;
        }
        else
        {
            List<PatientViewModel> lst = (List<PatientViewModel>)Session["templist"];

            lst.Add(new PatientViewModel()
                    {
                        Count = lst.Count + 1,
                        PatientAppointmentID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["PatientAppointmentID"]),
                        // BillNo = Request.Form["BillNo"],
                        Amount = double.Parse(Request.Form["Amount"]),
                        Description = Request.Form["Description"]
                    });

            Session["templist"] = lst;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = "";
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["AdminCookies"];

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                username = Convert.ToString(cookie.Values["UserName"]);
            }

            tblPatientBill patientbill = new tblPatientBill();
            patientbill.PatientAppointmentID = model.PatientAppointmentID;
            //  patientbill.BillNo = model.ID;
            patientbill.Amount = model.AmountTotal;
            patientbill.Description = model.Note;
            patientbill.Discount = model.Discount;
            patientbill.CreatedAt = model.CreatedAt;
            patientbill.CreatedBy = username;
            patientbill.is_active = true;

            db.tblPatientBills.Add(patientbill);
            db.SaveChanges();

            int PatientBill_ID = Convert.ToInt32(patientbill.ID);
            List<PatientViewModel> lst = (List<PatientViewModel>)Session["templist"];

            if (lst != null)
            {
                tblPatientBillDetail billdetail = new tblPatientBillDetail();

                foreach (var item in lst)
                {
                    billdetail.PatientBillID = PatientBill_ID;
                    billdetail.Amount = item.Amount;
                    billdetail.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    billdetail.CreatedBy = username;
                    billdetail.Description = item.Description;
                    billdetail.is_active = true;

                    db.tblPatientBillDetails.Add(billdetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                Session.Clear();
            }
                    return RedirectToAction("Print", new { Billid = @PatientBill_ID });
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and after when done with all the entries upon submit all the record is saved into the database.

Now what I am trying to do is if while entering the entries if the user want to delete any row he should be able to delete it from session and upon finalizing the remaining data should go into the DB for which i am doing the following approach:
Id is going to controller through Ajax call:

```
  $("body").on("click", "#tblBills .Delete", function () {
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var Id = row.find("span").html();
            console.log("Id");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Session_Delete",
                data: '{ID: ' + Id+ '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("hello");
                    $("#test").remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and in the controller, I am removing the row from session like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteBillSession(int ID)
{
    List<PatientViewModel> lst = (List<PatientViewModel>)Session["templist"];
    lst.Remove(lst.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Count == ID));

    Session["templist"] = lst;

    return Json(new { success = "Valid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

The problem is it is removing the row from session but it is deleting the last in the sequence not the one which i have selected to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone gets into the same situation the issue is resolved like this:

**View:**

```
<table id="tblBills" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:100px">Patient Appointmnet ID</th>
                                        <th style="width:100px">Amount</th>
                                        <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                                        <th style="width:40px">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    @{
                                         double? AmountTotal = 0;
                                        if (Session["templist"] != null)
                                        {
                                            List<PatientViewModel> lst = (List<PatientViewModel>)Session["templist"];
                                            int count = 0;


                                            foreach (var o in lst)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="Count" style="display:none">
                                                        <span>@count</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="AppointmentID">
                                                        <span>@o.PatientAppointmentID</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="Amount">
                                                        <span>@o.Amount</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="Description">
                                                        <span>@o.Description</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="Delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                AmountTotal += @o.Amount;
                                                count++;
                                            }}
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="4"> No Data Found</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </table>
```

**Ajax Call:**

```
$("body").on("click", "#tblBills .Delete", function () {
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var id= row.find("span").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Session_Delete",
                data: '{ID: ' + id+ '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#tblBills").load(window.location + " #tblBills");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Controller Method:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteBillSession(int ID)
        {
            List<PatientViewModel> lst = (List<PatientViewModel>)Session["templist"];
            lst.RemoveAt(ID);
            Session["templist"] = lst;
           // return new EmptyResult();
             return Json(new { success = "Valid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```